# How to wire cables - 2-gang switch 3 lamps

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've got a 2-gang switch in the wall. It's connected to a cable in a ceiling, that contains 4 cables: black, brown, blue and yellow-green (not included in schema).

**Schema:**
[image]

**Expected result:**

1. Left part of switch turns on left lamp.
2. Right part of switch turns on right lamps.

I'm not sure if my schema is correct. Could anyone take a look and validate, please?

**EDIT:**

Thank you gentlemen for your input so far.
I need to clarify some things. I'm from Poland, so colors are standarized for Europe:

- blue - neutral
- green-yellow - protective conductor
- brown - hot
- black - hot

Here you have a switch. Two buttons:

- left (black hot cable) - turns on/off left bulb.
- right (brown hot cable) - turns on/off two right bulbs.
  [image: Here you have a switch.]

Schema:

This is a cable from the ceiling. Colors are I already mentioned above.
[image]
Will it work as I expect?

Comment: What are the green boxes in your diagram? The switches? how are thay actually connected? Simple switches typically only have 2 terminals ...

Comment: Green boxes are connectors like that: http://www.sklep.elpin.pl/Img.ashx?Id=5480

My schema shows only cable from ceiling. The 2-gang switch is already connected and I don't have to do anything with it.

Comment: What purpose do these colored wires each serve?  What part of the world are you in?  In the US, hot is always the switched wire and neutral is not.  You appear to be switching two different colors of wires (and the diagram isn't so clear).

Comment: "gang" is not enough definition.  Please let us know the number of poles and throws in each switch, e.g. "DPDT" means doublepole-double-throw;  the colloquial "three-way"  switch is a  SPDT , and so on.

Comment: Wait - if you simply mean there are two switches in the box, then there is no cross-connection between the switches other than that they tap off the same source "hot" side.   The wire coloring is odd: USA is black, white, green while ISO is  brown, blue, green+yellow stripe.   What country are you in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **only** cable at the switch is brown-black-blue then blue is **not** a neutral.

Brown should be live (hot) to the switch; blue and black should be switched lives and should both be over-sleeved brown.

At some point you have to provide a neutral to the lights, as neutral is not run through the switch.

[image]